# A flashlight shines on a wall. Emmission or Reflection?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, geometric-optics

A flashlight shines on a wall.
As an observer, I can see the illuminated area from different positions in the room.
How do the rays of light come about that get into my eye?

[image]

For my understanding it can't be reflection.
Is it because photons with matching energy can be absorpt from the molecules at the wall and immidiatelly emissioned back in random direction and some are targeting my eyes?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phenomenon you are talking about is called "diffuse reflection" and it is due to the scattering of light by the atoms close to the surface of the wall.

Most materials diffuse away at least part of the light that shines on them. Diffuse reflection is therefore one of the main mechanisms that allow us to *see* the objects around us.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection

Comment: Thanks a lot pointing me to the right direction.